# Checking innerHTML values if empty or not for Array of Object

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check if below condition holds true:

```
var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName('customers');

    for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
       elemArray[i].id = i;
       var elem = document.getElementById(elemArray[i].id);
       var text = elem.innerHTML;
       text = text.toString();
       alert(text);
       if(text=="<br>"){
            alert('bingo');
            elem.style.visibility="hidden";
         }

     }
```

In the 1st alert I can see values as

```
 1. <br>ABC
 2. <br>XYZ
```

and for empty values I get:

```
1. <br>
2. <br>
```

so I am trying to compare it but "bingo" is not showing. What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have either special characters or spaces in the content. Remember == compares exact strings. i.e. `'<br>'` and `'<br> '` are different.

Here is a working jsfiddle for and it prints bingo just fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/1nxzxjdd/

Some answers mention using indexOf or contains method which might not be useful to OPs question because it looks like OP is interested in finding out values containing only `<br>`

Comment: Add this to the jsfiddle `text = text.toString().trim();` if the issue is cause by unnecessary white spaces at the end or start of the string `.trim()` will take care of that. http://jsfiddle.net/1nxzxjdd/1/